# How do I disable a tableview without obscuring the entire screen like in Whatsapp?

Tags: swift, uitableview, whatsapp, uisearchcontroller, obscured-view

How do I disable a tableview without obscuring the entire screen like in Whatsapp? The idea is when the `SearchBar` in the `SearchController` is still empty, the `tableview` gets dark. to `SearchController`, by default obscure the entire screen. Using `obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation`, also obscure the entire screen.

I'm using Xcode 9.3 - Swift 4.

[image: example of when I click on whatsapp searchbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution

1) Declare view

```
let keyboardView  = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width  , height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
```

2) Add Notification Observer and view color alpha  in `viewDidLoad`

```
        keyboardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

2) Remove Notification Observer use

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

3) add Constraints to view

```
func addConstraints() {
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: keyboardView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))            
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: keyboardView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: keyboardView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: keyboardView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute,multiplier: 1, constant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))

    }
```

4) Add keyboard show and hide methods

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in

            self.storeCollectionView.addSubview(self.keyboardView)
             self.addConstraints()
        })
   }

  @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in

            self.keyboardView.removeFromSuperview()
        })

   }
```

Comment: Thanks. When I placed horizontally the dark view does not fill the rest of the screen. What could I change for this to happen?

Comment: @OséiasRibeiro Please add to me screenshot

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/klpzhroe09a82ki/WhatsApp%20Image%202018-05-03%20at%2012.00.50.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: Sorry for not seeing a detail. I would like to keep the Cancel button as in WhatsApp.

Comment: I made the changes. It still has the same problem. StatusBar also has a delay in animation in relation to the view. I see this when I turn the iphone.

Comment: I had not noticed, the problem of statusBar had been before. The problem then is only with the view added, when turning horizontally.